# Error on python shelve when saving an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

I want to save all of my variables (including primitives, objects, lists, dictionaries, etc.) with python shelve. In my workspace, I have a few empty lists which will be used and filled on specific conditions or on the next steps of my code. Unfortunately, when I want to save my workspace with `python shelve` it raises an error on empty list keys. My code is as below:

```
for key in dir():   
    try:
        my_ws[key] = globals()[key]
    except TypeError:       
        print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `it raises an error on empty list keys` what do you mean? `my_ws[[]] = 'a'`? What is the expection you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shelve doesn't have problem with empty lists.

Please make sure:   1) you initialize the shelve object properly before using it.     2) exclude all elements that shelve cannot serialize.    It uses pickle module and all elements supported may be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Check if below code will work for you and if you get any errors.

```
import inspect
import shelve
my_ws = shelve.open('test')
for key in dir():
    if not inspect.ismodule(globals()[key]):
        try:
            my_ws[key] = globals()[key]
        except TypeError:       
            print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with pickling empty lists. But you will definitely get a key error when trying to find local variables (dir) in globals(). Except when called in global scope, but then dir() will return all kinds of names you don't want to save, like modules, functions, `__file__`, `__doc__` etc.

If the code you pasted is located in some function then try this:

```
def f():
    a = []
    b = []
    for k, v in locals().items():
        my_ws[k] = v
```